# PHP working out minutes difference

Tags: php, date

I am working out the months, days, hours and minutes between two dates, I have successfully got it to work out the months, days and minutes, but I cannot for the life of get it to work out the minutes, below is my code.

```
<?php
    $date1 = "2012-07-01 00:00:00";
    $date2 = "2012-09-30 00:00:00";

    $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
    $minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24) / (60*60*24) / (60*60));

    printf("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d minutes\n", $years, $months, $days, $minutes);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and most accurate way to approach this problem is to use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class. Otherwise you'll run into issues when you deal with anomalies in dates (leap year, etc).

```
$format = 'Y-m-d h:i:s';
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

// Create DateTime objs based on the above format
$t1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, "2012-07-01 00:00:00", $tz);
$t2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, "2012-09-30 00:00:00", $tz);

// Find the difference between them
$diff = $t1->diff( $t2);

// Print out the difference in each amount
$outputs = array( 'Y' => 'Year', 'm' => 'Month', 'd' => 'day', 'h' => 'hour', 'i' => 'minute', 's' => 'seconds');

foreach( $outputs as $key => $value)
    echo $diff->format( '%'.$key) . ' ' . $value . "\n";
```

This [outputs](http://codepad.viper-7.com/B6xGn4):

```
00 Year
2 Month
29 day
0 hour
0 minute
0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing your `$diff` variable as you work everything else out:

```
$years = floor($diff / 31557600); // 31557600 = 365.25 * 86400
$diff -= $years * 31557600;
// I'd skip months, since different months have a different number of days.
// If you *really* want it, calculate the number of months from the days below.
$days = floor($diff / 86400); // 86400 = 24 * 3600
$diff -= $days * 86400;
$hours = floor($diff / 3600); // 3600 = 60 * 60
$diff -= $days * 3600;
$minutes = floor($diff / 60);
$diff -= $minutes * 60;
// $diff now equals the number of seconds left over
```

Alternatively, look into PHP's [Date/Time object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2012-07-01 00:00:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2012-09-30 00:00:00");
$diff = $date1->diff($date2); // $diff is a DateInterval object
```

Look at [DateInterval->format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to determine how you want to format your output from `$diff`.

Answer (score 0):

Used to have one of the following functions, to convert seconds into days/weeks/hh:mm:ss time etc.
That should answer your query.

```
function duration ($sec, $padHours = false)  {
  if ($sec > 1209600) return "> ". intval(intval($sec) / 604800) . " weeks";
  if ($sec > 604800) return "1 week";
  if ($sec > 172800) return "> ". intval(intval($sec) / 86400) . " days";
  if ($sec > 86400) return "1 day";
  $hms = "";
  $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);
  $hms .= ($padHours)
        ? str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ":"
        : $hours. ":";
  $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
  $hms .= str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ":";
  $seconds = intval($sec % 60);
  $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  return $hms;

}
```